# How can I change the arguments to a method call using Mockito doAnswer?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following method call

```java
public Report retrieveReport(int rowSize){
...
}
```

and this method call is being done in another class as so

```java
Report report = reportBuilder.retrieveReport(Report.DEFAULT_ROW_SIZE);
```

As a part of integration testing, I would like to substitute the `Report.DEFAULT_ROW_SIZE` with my own variety of sizes.

I've tried creating a spy on the ReportBuilder, and then doing the following

```java
int testSize = 5;
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    args[0] = testSize;
    return invocation.callRealMethod();
}).when(reportBuilder).retrieveReport(anyInt());
```

The issue is that when mockito calls the real method, it passes the original argument value, `Report.DEFAULT_ROW_SIZE`, and doesn't pass in the modified argument `testSize`. Any idea of what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented whether or not altering the return value of `getArguments()` will alter the arguments used when `callRealMethod()` is called.

What you can try instead is to mock only the call for this specific value to call the method with a different value:

```java
int testSize = 5;
doAnswer(invocation -> reportBuilder.retrieveReport(testSize))
        .when(reportBuilder).retrieveReport(Report.DEFAULT_ROW_SIZE);
```